# How can I indent HTML or PHP code in Notepad ++ editor?

Tags: php, html, notepad++

How can I indent HTML or PHP code in notepad ++ editor to organize my code better?

Comment: You can indent by adding spaces or tabs. Is this a programming question?

Comment: If you like to see some standards regarding indenting and format your PHP code, have a look at the PSR-1/2 code styles: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md and https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want auto-formatting, look at [SourceFormatX](http://www.sourceformat.com/index.php), which is a paid plug-in for Notepad++.

Other than that, there are a few free plug-ins available on the [Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Central) which will format either HTML or PHP code.

Comment: one of the link "Notepad++ Wiki" is not working in the above answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally common practice to indent one level for each currently open "block". In PHP, a "block" is simply code between `{` and `}`. In HTML, a "block" is any tag that is not closed on the same line.

In Notepad++ (and many other code editors) you can select several lines of code and hit Tab to indent the entire selection (or Shift+Tab to outdent it). This should help keep your code tidy.

Another thing to note is that Notepad++ can collapse blocks for you. Next to the line numbers, you should see a tree with `[-]` boxes. You can click those to collapse the block they're marking, allowing you to get a better overview of your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a plugin to format your HTML, it is not clear if you only want to tab, but in common sense, I suppose you're looking for a software to reindent the code. There is a plugin Tidy2 in:

https://github.com/davegb3/NppTidy2

With this you can reformat all your HTML code, and change how to do it, which is often interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Select part of your code or any text and then press **tab**, it will indent all selected lines. Press **shift + tab** for unindent.